# In @OneToMany making One's side owner

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, db-schema

Let's say there is an `Employee`'s which has a collection of `Course`.

```
class Employee {
@OneToMany
private Set<Course> courses.
}
```

I want something like below

```
first_name | last_name | course_ids
Jill       |  Smith.   | 1,2,3
Eve        |  Jackson. | 1,4,5
```

I am not so advanced in hibernate, can someone please help.

Comment: That's not a good design because course_ids is not normalized. And this is not supported by JPA. You have to create a table employee_course. Is employee <-> course really one-to-many and not many-to-many?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Employee-Courses is just example. However, you can think it as Employee and ID.

Comment: So you have to store ids in a relation table. You can't store it as a list with ,

Answer (score 0):

The method that  I am about to show to you is the One to many  unidirectional method.
In your database you should create a table for courses and it must contain employee_id as a foreign key and an id of the course as a primary key.
Then, create the Course class as below.(let's assume that the name of the course table in the database is "course":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ='id')
    private int id;
    
    //You can add another fields based on your course table
   //add a constructor with no arguments, getters and setters
}
```

Notice that the employee_id is not  in the course class.Then create the employee class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="employee")
public class Employee {
    //ID and other fields
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="course_id")
    private List<Course> courses;
    
    //Constructor,getters and setters,...

}
```

You must define getters and setters in every Entity you create because Hibernate uses them to set the fields in the Entity with the value retrieved from the database